Leaky internally insulated ducts made worse by sealing - what to do?
House built in 1990s, ducts have been cleaned over time but have been leaky so had them internally sealed with areoseal.  This created a new problem - air not flowing to 1/2 the registers in the house.  Techs discovered that a large piece of INTERNAL insulation lining had come off in basement ducts and was blocking airflow to 1st floor. That removed, airflow restored to 1st floor but now 2nd floor not getting enough airflow.  How can I determine if internal lining detached in other parts of the system and how can this be remedied? If basement ducts were internally lined, is it likely that all ducts throughout the house were too?

A remote inspection camera seems in order here.

At this point all you can do is remove the registers on all the vents and examine the duct runs with an Endoscope camera and light. They are pretty inexpensive. If you verify that insulation has fallen, try some of the telescopic grab bars/hooks to remove it.  Can't really say if all ducts were internally sealed.  I've never really heard of spraying a sealer in an internally insulated duct.
